# C++ temporary class instantiation ambiguously

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

Let we have procedure formed as class. Only constructor call makes some side effect. No need to handle class instance in memory after call. Following code instantiate that class:

```
struct A{
    A(int){}
    };
int main() {

    A(0);//right. Pass const to ctor
    int x=0;
    A(x);//bad. Compiler interpret like A x;
    (A(x));//right. New temporary object passed to brackets
    A((int)x);//right. Pass temporary int to ctor

    return 0;
}
```

(see also on [Online IDE](http://ideone.com/0SAEZ7))

Why A(x); interpret as variable x declaration instead of temporary A object instantiaton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C++11 standard, ISO/EIC 14882 §6.8 [stmt.ambig] ¶1 (emphasis mine):

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statements* and declarations: An *expression-statement* with a function-style explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable
>   from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a `(`. **In those cases the statement is a declaration.**

To apply this to your question, `A(x);` can parse as either "call the function `A` / construct a temporary object of type `A`, and pass `x` as the only function/constructor argument" or "declare a variable `x` of type `A`."  The standard says that in this case, it should be parsed as a variable declaration.

Your other examples are not ambiguous because they cannot be parsed as a variable declaration, and so they are parsed as a call to `A`'s constructor.

Comment: Nice, I couldn't find that statement!

Answer (score 1):

That's because what you consider should be the parameter list to the ctor, `(x)` is being interpreted as "`x` in parentheses". Thus, `A(x)` is read as `A (x)` is read as `A x`.

In the other cases, the compiler has a hint suggesting that it should generate an `A` instance, calling the ctor with the arguments supplied.